# How to play sound on command?

Tags: bash

Every time i write g++ main.cpp, i want to play a sound.mp3.
But the problem is if i add alias like this

```
alias g++='play sound.mp3 | g++ -std=c++17'
```

I have to wait till sound.mp3 is over.
How to make them work simultaneously?

Edit: added code block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Play the sound in the background, with no connection between the processes:

```
alias g++='play -q sound.mp3 & g++ -std=c++17'
```

Adding `-q` avoids any output from `play`, which prevents it stopping because it’s trying to output while in the background.

Comment: it's also worth noting that many build configuration systems, especially things like `./configure` scripts will respect if you set `CC` (for gcc) and `CXX` environment variables - you could have scripts that just wrap your compiler calls. CMake has a facility to specify a program to launch the compilers: `cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_LAUNCHER=vlads_cool_script_that_plays_sound_and_runs_the_command_line_attached_as_arguments`. It's usually used for tools like `ccache`. This way, you can have very musical software builds. DISCLAIMER: never do this, you'll annoy yourself.